# Firebase in Swift: Password reset email attempt not sending to user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Absolutely love Firebase so far except it is not sending emails. Every time that I go on my console to reset one of my user's passwords, I click on the authentication tab on the left, go to one of my users, click on the right side of the user, and click on reset password. Then it sends an email to my personal email saying that the message wasn't delivered to "billybob123@email.com" and the reason is that "unsafe characters or length in username."

Now I know what the issue is here, there is no username. I have no idea how to set it. In my app, the users sign up and sign in with their email, but Firebase must not think that is their username. Also, the failure email shows the email that the server tried to send. In that email below, it shows the password reset link. Here is an example of the link below.

https://greenbananatech-jbs.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=chubW2CkIyYbJvAUviPYUevyHtr-KKYLjFRhABglpFkAAAFkGfcgkw&apiKey=AIzaSyDYrCkVfzNww2V_BuBSTfV85s2lSwW8hO4&lang=en

See what I think where the issue lies is that empty space after ".com". I think this is where the username is supposed to go. I just don't know how to set the username of the users. I have already changed the DISPLAY name of my users in my Xcode project but that doesn't do anything. Also when I click on the "faulty" link, it is in no way faulty because it works perfectly! Here is the picture of the failure email below.

Thanks so much.

[Top of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnLfI.png) 
[Bottom of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kBse.png)

Comment: This is unrelated to the link (link is ok and it never carries any username). It has to do with the mechanism to send the email. Are you using your own custom SMTP server?

Comment: Including links or images in questions should generally be avoided as links break and data changed. In this case it would be better to include the text of what you are seeing at that link.

Comment: As a test, log into your Firebase console, go to your apps Authentication section. Each listed user should have an identifier and a User UID. On the right of each user there are three dots - click that and select Reset Password. It should say "Send a password reset email", and then User Account and then underneath that show an email address. Is that working as I described? Is the email address correct or blank or what? If not, what are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem. I tried to configure Firebase SMTP using CPanel's outbound service, and I only received the error message. The problem is the "SMTP account username" field. Try passing the email address on it. It worked for me.